# IOS Google Map SDK Key ISSUE

Tags: ios, dictionary

I am developing ios Application which has Google Map IOS SDK integrated.
In developer environment, Map is working perfect even though there is wrong Map API Key.
But when I upload to Appstore, map is not working. We tried with static map key in appdelegate method.
And now we made the map key dynamic which comes from server but the `[GMSServices:@"KEY"]` this code is not in appdelegate metohd. Now I am getting the below error if I check the log from device :

```
[GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:longitude:zoom:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x26c734
```

And also please let me know , do we need to purchase a business map key for commercial use because now we are using free map api key.

Please help me resolving the issue.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: That error has nothing to do with the API key. It appears to be some sort of bad installation. The API key only controls whether you get valid data from Google or not.

Answer (score -1):

-Created a single view application with disabled “USE STORYBOARDS”
    and “ARC” on.

-Created a API key using bundle identifier of my project which is : com.MapTest

-Copied GoogleMaps.framework bundle into Framework group.

-Copied GoogleMaps.bundle from “Resources” folder into Framework group

-Added all of the following framework:

```
AVFoundation.framework 
CoreData.framework
CoreLocation.framework
CoreText.framework
GLKit.framework
ImageIO.framework
libicucore.dylib 
libstdc++.dylib 
libz.dylib
OpenGLES.framework
QuartzCore.framework 
SystemConfiguration.framework
```

-Fixed the default Architectures and Other Linker Flags:

-Imported  and added google API key in
    AppDelegate

Kindly check what ever mentioned in the site you should do that.
http://www.quora.com/Having-probem-with-googlemap-sdk

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/start

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: sure.. here i gave some detail about google map sdk what ever in the link.